# How to disable second mouse pointer in Asus Zenbook - Unbuntu 22.04

Tags: mouse, asus

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on Asus Zenbook UX461F. I see a second mount pointer which moves/selects files folders on its own. How do I get rid of the second mount pointer.

- I disabled touchpad in BIOS
- I am using Logitec M330 wireless mouse

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:16                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet stylus:16                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet eraser:16                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet cursor:16                 id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```